# Prevent Navigating Back At All Costs in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, expo

Here is a basic react native app

App.js

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator ({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
{
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
  headerMode: 'none',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
  },
}
);

const App = new createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default App;
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class KeyScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Press the button to login</Text>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                }}
                >
                    <Text>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
});
```

HomeScreen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>You are logged in until the app is deleted!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

With this setup and gestures disabled, you cant get back to the login screen from the homescreen but I am not confident that you won't be logged off after restarting the phone or closing and opening the app. Is there a way to ensure that you cannot go back to the login screen after pressing the button? With my current app setup, going back to the login screen would essentially lock you out of the app since there would no longer be an access key in the database for the user.

Comment: @tadman This is an IOS app, not a website. In most mobile apps, once you have logged in, you stay logged in unless you choose to logout or reinstall the app. In my code, no information is stored and you need to login again every time you reopen the app which is impractical and annoying. I need to fix that.

Comment: @tadman gotcha. that would definitely not be a good behavior in a web app haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`createSwitchNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html)

```js
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';

const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  headerMode: 'none',
})

const RootSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Main: { screen: MainStack },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login'
})

const App = new createAppContainer(RootSwitch);

export default App;
```

If you want a user to be able to stay logged in, even when they reopen the app, use [`AsyncStorage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) or [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save what you're using to check if they're logged in. Check for that on `componentDidMount` of `LoginScreen`, and navigate to `Main` if it exists and is valid.

Comment: How would the switching look from one to another?

Comment: You would have to use `this.props.navigation.navigate` explicitly to navigate between those routes. Switch prevents the user from using any back navigation to go to other switch routes. The transition is immediate, there is no transition animation.

Comment: I have also added an explanation of how to automatically navigate to the Main stack if the user is already logged in.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.